# How to blend a tranparent layer onto the base layer without affecting the "base color"?(Image Editor)

Tags: texture-painting, uv-image-editor

While trying to blend a decal layer(alpha with mix blend-type) on a base layer(mix blend-type) in the Image Editor,blender either doesn't paint anything (Color = 0) or completely changes the base color (Color = 1).

As seen from this [video@1.15](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ChU9.gif),the same setup works from the compositor.

How to blend a tranparent layer onto the base layer without affecting the "base color" in the Image Editor?

[image]

Comment: Are you only interested in solutions using 2.79? I would instead use a solid texture of color and use a stencil between them, black being transparent and white being the color - and this would allow for graded value to fade the color.

Comment: Hmm,aren't the blend calculations  across Blender versions supposed to be the same ? Also , I got the result with your earlier answer, by switching layer blend to "Overlay".

Comment: 2.8 and up make more use of shader nodes so the manipulation of textures in the tree is easier to get complex out put and to reuse a single texture in multiple ways.